# Producing a gradient effect for a listing screen in jQuery mobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

![enter image description here][1]I'm working on a jQuery mobile app. Is there any possibility that I produce a gradient effect on my listing screen? My current code is below:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
<h1>Header</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="content-primary" >
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-icon="false">
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333;">Sunday</a></h3>
    <p class="topic"><strong>Sub</strong></p>
    <p>Date</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333;">Monday</a></h3>
    <p class="topic"><strong>Sub </strong></p>
    <p>Date</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333;">Tuseday</a></h3>
    <p class="topic"><strong>Sub</strong></p>
    <p>Date</p>
  </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: define "gradient effect"

Comment: @ Jonas Grumann, can i add it to each row or for whole screen. pls suggest

Comment: I still don't understand the question. Can you show an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: add a custom class to your `<a>` element and add your custom background CSS to this class. You might have to overwrite the `background-image` property if it is set.

Comment: @jonas Gruman , Something like in image

Comment: @ frequent , thank you for your valuable reply .
I'll try and let know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set gradient background to `ui-listview` and `ui-btn`'s background to `transparent`.

```
.ui-listview {
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fc3232 0%, #ffd242 100%);
}

.ui-listview li .ui-btn {
   background: transparent;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6Mycs/)**

Comment: @ Omar , what if i have navbar with 3 different tabs , how can i apply gradient effect to 3 different navbar..? please suggest

Comment: @user3632072 navbar or tabs?

Comment: @user3632072 its better to post a separate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55850/discussion-between-omar-and-user3632072).